# How to keep track of uploading progress across multiple devices with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, file-upload

I've been using Firebase's StorageUploadTask type to monitor uploading progress to storage. However I was wondering what the best way would be to monitor uploading progress from multiple devices, say for example if I upload something from my laptop to Firebase and want to be able to see the uploading progress from my phone. Is there a way I can pass a StorageUploadTask through Firebase, or load a StorageUploadTask by URL or id? Thanks!

Ideally, I would be able to do something like:

**From a desktop application:**

```
let uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(from: path)
```

**From a mobile application**
(linked to the same Firebase database)

```
let uploadTask = Firebase.getUploadTask(fromRef: storageRef)
uploadTask.observe(.progress) { ... }
```

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'd like to know if there's a way to pass a StorageUploadTask through Firebase, so I can keep track of the uploading progress from multiple devices. @DougStevenson

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pass through to Firebase".  I think it would help if you edit the question to explain in more detail what your specific case is, and what your implementation needs to do at the end of the day.

Comment: I added an example of what the function I'm looking for may look like. I am just curious if something similar to this functionality exists. @DougStevenson

Comment: If you're asking if multiple devices can track the progress of an upload being performed? Sure. But why? And, the code in the question won't work for that use case (on the other devices), the local device will need to track the progress and write data out to a Firebase node as the task progresses. The other devices will need to have an observer on that node so they will receive events.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to simply "pass through" an upload or download task to share between clients.  Your best bet is to have a local listener on each task with code to update some shared location (perhaps a Realtime Database node or Firestore document) with the progress of each transfer.  The updates could then be listened to by each client that know the location of the updates.

Comment: Okay thanks, Doug. This is what I figured the answer to this question would be; thanks for the help!